# HUE failed to access file systems

Tags: hue

I downloaded HUE from https://github.com/cloudera/hue through git clone and compiled it successfully. However, it shows that some connection errors happen, which means it failed to connect to my local files or HDFS file systems.

Error info from command lines:

> [11/Jan/2021 03:58:33 +0000] cluster      INFO     Resource Manager
> not available, trying another RM: YARN RM returned a failed response:
> HTTPConnectionPool(host='localhost', port=8088): Max retries exceeded
> with url:
> /ws/v1/cluster/apps?finalStatus=UNDEFINED&limit=1000&user.name=hue&user=jyy&startedTimeBegin=1609761513000&doAs=jyy
> (Caused by NewConnectionError('<urllib3.connection.HTTPConnection
> object at 0x7fd4931e4f10>: Failed to establish a new connection:
> [Errno 111] Connection refused',)).

on localhost:8080:

> Could not connect to any of [('127.0.0.1', 10000)] (code
> THRIFTTRANSPORT): TTransportException("Could not connect to any of
> [('127.0.0.1', 10000)]",)

dashboard, schedulers, documents all reported error. For example, hdfs reported following error:

> Cannot access: /user/jyy. The HDFS REST service is not available.
> HTTPConnectionPool(host='localhost', port=50070): Max retries exceeded
> with url: /webhdfs/v1/user/jyy?op=GETFILESTATUS&user.name=hue&doas=jyy
> (Caused by NewConnectionError('<urllib3.connection.HTTPConnection
> object at 0x7fd4931dc210>: Failed to establish a new connection:
> [Errno 111] Connection refused',))

Could anyone figure out what the problem is? Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If your Hadoop services are not on localhost, you will need to update the Hue [configuration](https://docs.gethue.com/administrator/configuration/) to point to them.